# How to keep a form's entered values when the user changes the website language via Django's i18n/setlang?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-i18n

I'm using `Django 1.9.9` with the `i18n set_language view` to change website languages.

I have some pages with forms on them, e.g. for collecting project-specific user data. When a user enters data into such a form, but changes the language before saving the form, the entered data is lost.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small js event handler that on saves all the data in localstorage when clicking the set language link, and repopulates the form on page load.